# Is it possible to setup a mock of all overloads of a method in the same way without typing out all of them?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have mock of `Serilog.ILogger`, and I want to verify that no overloads of `logger.Error(...)` was called. There are currently 10 overloads, so I would want to avoid setting up every one of them. The test would also break in the future if they added more overloads.

So, instead of this:

```
var loggerMockSetup = new Mock<Serilog.ILogger>(MockBehavior.Loose);
loggerMockSetup.Verify(x => x.Error(It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Never);
loggerMockSetup.Verify(x => x.Error(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Object[]>()), Times.Never);
loggerMockSetup.Verify(x => x.Error(It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Never);
// ... and so on for all the overloads
```

Can I do something like the following?

```
var loggerMockSetup = new Mock<Serilog.ILogger>(MockBehavior.Loose);
loggerMockSetup.VerifyAllOverloads(x => x.Error, Times.Never);
```

It has to be specific to all overloads to `x.Error(...)` and not all methods on the object, because I have unrelated calls to e.g. `x.Information(...)`.

Comment: Most of the time we want to make sure that a given overload is being called in a given amount of times. Why do you need to do the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following options:

1. Create a custom extension method `VerifyAllOverloads` → less work, but needs to be modified as soon as new overloads are added to `ILogger`
2. Create a custom implementation of `ILogger` (e. g. `UnitTestLogger`) which forwards all overload calls to a common method. Then you can react onto this common method → less work, but needs to be modified as soon as new overloads are added to `ILogger`
3. Use reflection/source generators to fetch all overloads of `ILogger` and build a custom assertion based on this → more work, but doesn't need to be modified as soon as new overloads are added to `ILogger`

Comment: If this suffices your needs, consider marking it as an answer so that the question gets closed :)